# How to call upon the "second lowest" of a series of values?

Tags: arrays, sorting, pine-script

Essentially what the title says, I have a series of code that looks at the values of 5 EMA's and I need to sort them and call upon different ones (the second lowest, or the middle EMA of the 5 for example)

I did a loop around kind of cheat by simply adding an extra EMA that has a farther multiplier but not including that in my calculations but it's not getting me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array from those values and then sort it. After that, just access the elements of the sorted array as you wish.

Here is a small function and test script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

// Will return NaN if the index is out of bounds
f_get_sorted_value(p_array, p_idx) =>
    float ret_val = na
    len = array.size(p_array)

    if ((len > 0) and (p_idx < len))
        ret_val := array.get(p_array, p_idx)

    ret_val    

val1 = -1
val2 = 0
val3 = 1
val4 = 10
val5 = 100

my_array = array.from(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5)
array.sort(my_array, order.ascending)

lowest_val1 = f_get_sorted_value(my_array, 0)
lowest_val2 = f_get_sorted_value(my_array, 1)
lowest_val3 = f_get_sorted_value(my_array, 2)
lowest_val4 = f_get_sorted_value(my_array, 3)
lowest_val5 = f_get_sorted_value(my_array, 4)
lowest_val6 = f_get_sorted_value(my_array, 5)

s_array = "Sorted array: " + str.tostring(my_array) + "\n"
str_lowest_val1 = "Lowest value 1: " + str.tostring(lowest_val1) + "\n"
str_lowest_val2 = "Lowest value 2: " + str.tostring(lowest_val2) + "\n"
str_lowest_val3 = "Lowest value 3: " + str.tostring(lowest_val3) + "\n"
str_lowest_val4 = "Lowest value 4: " + str.tostring(lowest_val4) + "\n"
str_lowest_val5 = "Lowest value 5: " + str.tostring(lowest_val5) + "\n"
str_lowest_val6 = "Lowest value 6: " + str.tostring(lowest_val6)

if (barstate.islast)
    s = s_array + str_lowest_val1 + str_lowest_val2 + str_lowest_val3 + str_lowest_val4 + str_lowest_val5 + str_lowest_val6
    label.new(bar_index, high, s, textcolor=color.white)
```

[image]

Please note that `array.sort()` will modify the original array. But it should be fine in your case. If you want to avoid that, then you need to create a copy of the array.